# Android emulator doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed all the necessary files from android site, but when I run my emulator it just displays "ANDROID" and nothing else.  I am using Intel Dual core (2.20GHz), ASUS motherboard and 3gb of RAM.  Whats the prob I couldnt understand.. Even one of my friend using Intel Dual core(1.80GHz) with 1gb of RAM running smoothly then whats my problem.

Comment: How much time did you wait before closing the emulator? try waiting a little more :)

Answer (score 3):

The emulator is slow becasue it is, of all things, emulating a completely different architecture (arm), and if it's the first time you've started it it has to create the memory file toi emulate the SD card you told it was there.

My bet would be that you simply didn't wait long enough for it to boot up.

You can save yourself some time by checking the option to save snapshots and start from them (it'll save you start time after the first time at least).  Another emulator speed-up is to open your run configuration for whatever app you are going to run, click on the "Target" tab, and check the box to "Disable Boot Animation".

Comment: That not 1st time..When I am launching emulator with 1.5 or1.6 its take more or less 30mins every time with showing some error and when I am launching amdroid 2.2 its doesnt respond at all..just showing "ANDROID".

Comment: Added to my answer another tip to possibly speed up your emulator boot.

Comment: I can start up VirtualBox hosting a full-featured OS in a few seconds. Hard to believe that the same machine can't emulate a lightweight OS on a mobile processor in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The Emulator must be booting. Just waiting for it. The time is depending on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might want to look at the GPU support that comes with the new SDK. It's much faster http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html